# How to use google map API in a "src" javascript script

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use google map API in my index.html :

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

I can use Google Map with `google.maps` object in my index.html

But, i can't use `google.maps` object in my script `<script src="myscript.js"></script>`. How can I use it ?

Comment: Are you loading the googleapis script before your myscript.js?

Comment: You can only use the maps api when `initAutocomplete()` gets called.

Comment: This needs a minimal complete verifiable example. Please post the minimum code  necessary to recreate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Maps libraries load asynchronously, so they may not be fully loaded by the time your `myscript.js` file is executed.

The `callback` parameter in the URL for the Google Maps library allows you to specify a function to be executed when the library has loaded, so you should wrap your code in this function.

In your example the callback function is called 'initAutocomplete' so you should wrap your initialisation code in a global function with that name:

```
window.initAutocomplete = function() {
    // You can use google.maps here
}
```

In this instance, you should include `myscript.js` before the Google Maps library, so the callback function is available.